# How to route inbound cloud traffic back to my home PC?

Tags: security, ip, routing, privacy

While traveling away from home, I want to connect to services hosted at my home but without directly using my home IP address. I'm wary of other hotel guests, Starbucks patrons, any bad actors thereof, discovering my home IP address while connected.

To achieve this layer of obfuscation, I think I need to setup a cloud server with my "virtual" home IP address (something I can rotate/expire), that simply routes traffic back to my true home IP address transparently.

- What's the recommended method for this and what do I call it? a Cloud NAT? IP Proxy?
- Can both Linux and Windows Server generally be configured to route this way?
- Am I overlooking a simpler solution?

Comment: Why do you worry about others finding out your home IP address? A much simpler (and cheaper) solution would be to subscribe to a commercial VPN service.

Comment: @StarCat , good question.  Some of the locations I will be connecting from ban or block commercial VPNs.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might involve running a tunnel from your cloud server/VPS to your home network. That way only the IP of your VPS will leak. It is of course vital that the traffic you are generating is encrypted itself otherwise the payload will leak. For example, if you access a HTTP server at home by making a request to the VPS which will be (securely) tunneled to your home, then the information is not secured.
You could get around this by having all service use SSL or by using VPN to the cloud and VPN from the cloud to your home network.

This seems like a simple approach and I'm sure that it is supported by both Windows and Linux systems. There are other solutions that might solve your issue aswell like Mobile IP and IPsec, but the problem here is that devices that are not under your control might need to be configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Is "running a tunnel" from cloud to home the same solution as a VPN from cloud to home? In other words what packages or online guides should I be googling for to do this?

Comment: "Running a tunnel" is just the broader term of which a VPN is a specific way to achieve a tunnel. If you want something more concrete that you can go ahead in researching and installing I recommend OpenVPN. Maybe terms like "site-to-site vpn using OpenVPN" may lead you to appropriate information.

Comment: In anothet comment you stated that you are worried about commercial VPNs getting blocked. I recommend to setup your OpemVPN in a "firewall friendly" way (e.g. listen on HTTPS port).